# I want to create a alphabetical navigation for custom taxonomy in WordPress without affect on the website design

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, directory-listing, alphabetical-sort

I want to create alphabetical navigation for custom taxonomy in WordPress without effect on the website design? if a user clicks on any alphabet like A, then it will show all listing categories start with A, also same condition filter for listing data

I have tried some plugins like A_Z listing, alphabetic pagination(not working at all, always ask for the premium version, how can I use it), A2Z Alphabetical Archive Links(work only on posts not for custom listing categories)

/test/#letter-B only show this on the address bar, but not filtering

Answer (score 1):

So here is a little something I came up with. You get the taxonomy in alphabetical order. Then you add the letters to a filter. Then use some javascript to filter for ya. Hope that helps!

```
    $terms = get_terms( array (
        'hide_empty' => 'false',
        'taxonomy'   => 'your_taxonomy',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'name',
    ));

    $filter_letters = array();
    $tax_wrap;
    $filter_wrap = '<div class="filter-wrap">';
    foreach($terms as $t) :
        $letter = substr( $t->name, 0, 1 );
        if(!in_array($letter, $filter_letters)) {
            $filter_letters[] = $letter;
            $filter_wrap .= '<span id="letter-' . $letter . '" class="letter">' . $letter . '</span>';
        }
        $tax_wrap .= '<div class="letter-' . $letter .' tax-row">
                        <a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link( $t )) .'">' . $t->name .'</a>
                    </div>';

    endforeach;
    $filter_wrap .= '</div>';

    ob_start();
    echo $filter_wrap;
    echo $tax_wrap;
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function( $ ){
            $('.filter-wrap .letter').click(function() {
                $('.tax-row').hide();
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                $('.' + id).show();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
```